# How to use xml definition in SharePoint list which is configured using BCS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, bcs, sql

I have a SQL database server with 3 columns ID, Location, FileType, I have used BCS service to connect SharePoint with this table.

Now for example Location field is int type something like 19 means Newyork. This is defined in XML file. Is there any way I can show the city name rather than 19 as number in SharePoint List

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do a lookup to another table that has

ID , NameOfPlace

19, "NewYork"

Since you said the ID and names were in XML, you will have to import the excel.